# Erro code: 65543 PDF conversion of doc not happening in SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word-automation

I Had created a solution containing event receiver to convert document from word to pdf on item added event.

While event is firing when document is added to library and also event receiver code run's successfully but pdf file are not added to same document library which I am doing.

I tried the powershell script to set:

```
 $sp.disableSandbox=$true
Property 'disableSandbox' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:1
+ $sp.disableSandbox=$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

While my service exist see:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $sp


Name            : Word Automation Service
Id              : ca6b4a52-140e-49bf-ac50-ac5aec8315a5
ApplicationPool : SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool Name=WAS-Service
Database        : QueueDatabase Name=WordAutomation
Status          : Online
```

What's wrong?

**Note:** I'm using virtual machine as standalone server where database and domain controller are on same server instance i.e. single machine. Is there any relation of issue with configuration?

Comment: Are you running the code as a farm administrator in elevated powershell window? I think it might actually be a permission issue where that property is not settable with your current permissions

Comment: Yes, I'm a farm administrator. And even this property 'disableSandbox' is not appearing in intellisense in powershell. Mine environment is SP2013

Comment: Make sure PowerShell's reflection hasn't provided getter and setter methods instead of a property: $sp.set_DisableSandbox($true)

Comment: However, in my environment, the property is unchanged: DisableSandbox                          Property   System.Boolean DisableSandbox {get;set;} even when the process isn't elevated.

Comment: I even checked the $sp.set_DisableSandbox($true). But this not exist!

Comment: And @Robert, I'm using virtual machine as standalone server where database and domain controller are on same server instance i.e. single machine. Is there any relation of issue with configuration?

Comment: Pretty sure document convention does not work on that setup

Comment: okay Robert, is there no other way to make it work on same configuration :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while back too - the issue is when using WAS when your SP server is also a domain controller - which is typical in development environments.

This was not an issue with SP2010 running Win Server 2008, but has crept in now with Win Server 2012 AD domain controllers.

The reason being that WAS requires elevated privileges to run - something you can't do when it's a domain controller too because of the security settings enabled by default on domain controllers.

Hope this helps!
David